# Bluetooth settings lists headphone as paired, unable to connect

Tags: windows-10, laptop, audio, bluetooth

**Background**

I have a Sony (MDR-ZX770) bluetooth headphone that I have successfully been able to use on my Windows 10 laptop.

**However**

Now, after doing a shutdown/restart, it doesn't work anymore. Whenever I turn on my headphone, it's bluetooth connection status is listed as `paired`, but sound is played on the laptop's speakers.

[image]

I know my headphone is on because the power light is blinking blue.

I can (re)connect with my smartphone without issue.

> What can I do to have the headphone connected and working as expected?

Comment: Have you pressed `Connect` on the Action Centre (**Win** + **a**)?

Comment: I didn't know that exists, that seems to help. Odd that such is separate from Bluetooth settings ... please formulate it as an answer so I can accept it.

Answer (score 1):

You need the Bluetooth Settings in order to pair a device, but this doesn't actually connect to the device (though, confusingly, a paired device can show here as connected, even when it isn't).

To use a Bluetooth device, you need to press the **Connect** button on the Action Centre (<kbd>Win</kbd>+<kbd>a</kbd>). You can then choose from a list which includes previously paired devices, though you cannot pair a new device from here.

I am not aware of any auto-connect options in Win10, though there may well be third-party software to do this.